Run time depends on code after the measured part
Consider the following C++23 program (online).
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <print>


constexpr size_t NWrites = 10000000000;
#define DEST_STORAGE static
#define NEWLINE_CHAR '\n'
#define F_CONSTNESS  const


static double MeasureDuration(auto&& callable)
{
    const auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    callable();
    const auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return std::chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count();      // seconds
}


template <unsigned Iterations>
static void RepeatWrite(volatile char& dest)
{
    RepeatWrite<Iterations - 1>(dest);
    dest = 0x42;
}


template <>
void RepeatWrite<0>(volatile char& dest)
{
}


template <unsigned Iterations>
static void RunSimulation()
{
    const double duration = MeasureDuration([] {
        DEST_STORAGE volatile char dest;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < NWrites / Iterations; i++)
            RepeatWrite<Iterations>(dest);
    });

    std::printf("Duration_%u = %.2f s.", Iterations, duration);
    std::print("{}", NEWLINE_CHAR);
}


int main()
{
    RunSimulation<1>();
    RunSimulation<2>();

    static F_CONSTNESS bool f = false;
    if (f) {
        RunSimulation<3>();
        RunSimulation<4>();
    }
}

RunSimulation() writes a char approximately NWrites times (this varies by a small amount because of integer division).
Combining the three #define's DEST_STORAGE, NEWLINE_CHAR and F_CONSTNESS I built 8 versions of the program with Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.4 (cl.exe v19.40.33812). All were x86-64 with optimizations. On my CPU (AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5650U) I consistently got the following measurements.




v1
v2
v3
v4
v5
v6
v7
v8




DEST_STORAGE
static
static
static
static






NEWLINE_CHAR
'\n'
'\n'
"\n"
"\n"
'\n'
'\n'
"\n"
"\n"


F_CONSTNESS
const

const

const

const



duration_1
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~2.56 s


duration_2
~2.56 s
~2.56 s
~1.28 s
~2.56 s
~1.28 s
~1.28 s
~1.28 s
~1.28 s



I determined, that duration_2 ≈ 0.5 * duration_1, except those three peculiar cases v1, v2 and v4, which I cannot explain.
In main() the part in the if never runs. If F_CONSTNESS is nothing, the code is there, but it doesn't run. If it is const, the entire if is optimized away.
I could ask a couple of intriguing questions about the above table, but let's focus on one: the difference between v3 and v4. How can duration_2 depend on F_CONSTNESS, which appears in the code after the calculation of duration_2?

Don't measure time using high_resolution_clock.  Use a proper profiling tool it will tell you how many cycles where spent why. For example if branch predicition (failure) will be your bottlneck or not.

Rationale for not using high_resolution_clock for timing. If the backing clock can do stuff like jump backward, your measurements are going to be questionable.

Did you examine the code at Godbolt?

You guys can complain about the clock, but that's purely a theoretical concern that explains nothing. The MS standard library implementation of chrono has using high_resolution_clock = steady_clock.

That's a good argument for just using steady_clock so that there is no doubt about the clock jumping around.  It won't change the facts (on Windows).  But it will change what readers have to worry about.

Is this a huge unrolled loop of byte stores?  So you're measuring code-fetch bandwidth maybe from L2 or L3 cache.  Alignment could matter, and so can various confounding effects like CPU frequency changes (since you're measuring in wall-clock time not core clock cycles).  See also Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?

Oh, no it's not a a huge unrolled loop.  The iteration count for RepeatWrite is only 1 to 3.
